# C#: Check if administrator has write access to a file

Tags: c#, security, impersonation

**The Problem**:
I need to check if a user (local user or domain user, either one is possible) has write access to a file (if you're curious, `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`. This file is protected by Windows and you need to be an administrator to write to it.)

**My Solution**:
The general construct is:

```
using (Impersonator impersonator = new Impersonator(domain, username, password))
{
 try
 {
  using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(appHostConfigPath))
    {
     return true;
    }
  catch
  {
     return false;
  }
 }
```

As you can imagine, the Impersonator class is an IDisposible which uses native interop to call LogonUser. Nothing too creative, and it works.

**Where I am stuck:**
On Windows OSs with UAC enabled, this function always return `false` even if the user specified by *username* is an administrator. Even though my program is running elevated as an administrator, I suspect what's happening is that the impersonated code is running as a limited administrator. Hence, the method is returning false.

I don't have any creative solutions to this. Can anyone help?

Comment: If your code is all in one process, if it's elevated then UAC isn't the issue. Have you tried turning off UAC on the same computer to see if it changes? (You might need to reboot, remember.)

Comment: @Lambert: He said he's using the `LogonUser` API, which [returns a restricted token](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/8aa1cd61-c2db-4e22-81ee-a55b12e6e027).  Whether the current process is elevated isn't going to change the behavior of `LogonUser`.

Comment: Huh... but did you try turning off UAC completely, on that computer? It's weird why having it on would change the behavior, if the program is elevated...

Comment: @Lambert: Ben is right, LogonUser gives you a restricted token, which is why I believe I can't check if the user has write access to the file (because the tokens don't match)

Comment: @Bilal: Even if UAC is turned off?

Comment: @Lambert - seems to work ok if UAC is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Could you look at the exception? Is it with the permissions or "File not found exception"?
Because on Windows 7 it is at

> %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

may be the same with Windows Vista too.

Comment: Thanks Vijay, I just had the path written down incorrectly on stackoverflow. I have it right in my program. The exception is unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

How about [GetFileSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446639.aspx) and [GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446637.aspx)?

The second link has an example which is actually quite complete (in C++).